# How do I check my version of GNOME-Shell?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

There's got to be some simple way I'm missing, but for the life of me I can't find it. How do I check my version of GNOME-Shell?

Comment: allow me to add that in addition to needing to know the version of `gnome-shell` one is running, for those specific tasks & troubleshooting that require this information, one often also needs to know if they're running wayland or not (which does not depend on the version of gnome-shell, but rather needs to be checked separately) https://askubuntu.com/questions/904940/how-can-i-tell-if-i-am-running-wayland

Answer (score 405, accepted):

Just type

```
gnome-shell --version
```

into a terminal.

Comment: I tired it, but it didn't work. Got an error >> **gnome-shell: error: no such option: --version**

Comment: @VinayChalluru: type `gnome-shell -h`. This should give you the available options and allow you to copy and paste  `--version` to make sure you've got everything right (the hyphens can be especially tricky).

Answer (score 27):

The [gnome-shell man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/gnome-shell.1.html) doesn't show --version as an option. Assuming you have installed it from the ubuntu repositories then you can look up the version in the repository. To just show the version:

```
apt-cache show gnome-shell | grep Version
```

On Ubuntu Maverick (10.10) I get

```
Version: 2.31.5-2ubuntu2
```

Note that this works whether or not the package is installed. You can also look up [all packaged versions of gnome-shell on all ubuntu versions](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnome-shell&searchon=names&section=all) on http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Comment: The output could show several versions.

Comment: Yep: 
`Version: 3.12.2-0ubuntu0~trusty2`
`Version: 3.10.4-0ubuntu5.2`
`Version: 3.10.4-0ubuntu5`

Comment: rather than `apt-cache`, a better tool for this specific task (querying the state of installed vs available packages) would be `dpkg`, e.g., use `$ dpkg -l gnome-shell` and verify the output is prefixed by `ii` or run: `$ dpkg -l gnome-shell | grep '^ii'` See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124914/distinction-between-apt-cache-and-dpkg-l