# How can I tell if I am running Wayland?

Tags: xorg, wayland

Wayland is the default display server for Ubuntu 17.10 "[on supported systems](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes/#Ubuntu_Desktop)". But how can I tell if my platform is supported and I'm actually using Wayland?

Comment: Why don't you just look into process? `pgrep Xorg` or something like `ps -ef | grep " :0"`

Comment: Useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202891/how-to-know-whether-wayland-or-x11-is-being-used

Answer (score 244, accepted):

Open the terminal and type in:

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

Check if it prints `wayland`.

Comment: This would be the best answer in my opinion, as it doesn't require installing or running another programme.

Answer (score 27):

You could install `mesa-utils-extra` and run `es2gears_wayland`
If the app runs, you are running Wayland.

For a fun way to check whether a specific app is using Wayland or XWayland,
run `xeyes`. The eyes will move if the cursor is over an X or XWayland
window.

Or run this in a terminal:

```
env | grep -i wayland
```

If there is no output, you are not running Wayland.

Comment: i sadly can't install xeyes on 18.04 :(

Answer (score 16):

Use that command in the Ubuntu terminal:

```
echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
```

Look at the value returned. If on wayland it will return

```
gnome-wayland

ubuntu-wayland  #  Ubuntu 20.10
```

Comment: cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager

Comment: This answer is not correct for Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Looks like since wayland became the default dm for gnome it says `gnome` if you are running wayland and `gnome-xorg` if you are on xorg.

Comment: It now says "ubunu-xorg" for xorg and just "ubuntu" for wayland.

Comment: @krumpelstiltskin: Running Xorg, getting 'ubuntu' here.

Comment: I got `gnome` and am running Wayland

Comment: @krumpelstiltskin Same in my case. Running X11, got "Ubuntu".

Answer (score 15):

**Settings > About > Windowing System**

On Ubuntu 21.04, you can also see it from the Settings GUI (Win key, type Settings, select. Executable name: `gnome-control-center`), which is nice.

The default is Wayland on that system, 21.04 appears to be the first release where it was the default: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/01/ubuntu-21-04-will-use-wayland-by-default

[image]

If I change to X11 as mentioned at: [How do you switch from Wayland back to Xorg in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) it says:

> Windowing System: X11

instead.

As mentioned at: [Ubuntu 21.04: how to enable Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338874/ubuntu-21-04-how-to-enable-wayland) however, if Ubuntu detects that you don't have the hardware support, it fallbacks to X11 by default.

Also, the NVIDIA 460 driver doesn't support Wayland, and X11 becomes your only choice once you install it.

BTW, the 21.04 minimal ISO install (which has Wayland and no NVIDIA driver, which is proprietary and needs to be installed manually later) has a known bug that crashed my UI every other day: [Ubuntu UI screen image freezes randomly during usage after fresh 21.04 install, suspecting Wayland or Nouveau](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344736/ubuntu-ui-screen-image-freezes-randomly-during-usage-after-fresh-21-04-install) making it unusable. The problem stopped when I installed the nvidia driver and used X11.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this answer generalizes, but I found that running `xrandr` will show different monitor names if running wayland vs. not:

```
xrandr --listmonitors
# On Ubuntu: 0: +*eDP-1 4384/344x2466/193+3840+0  eDP-1

# On Ubuntu-wayland: 0: +XWAYLAND0 1920/340x1080/190+0+0  XWAYLAND0
```

Comment: This is the only one on this page that works from SSH.

Answer (score 1):

If you execute `echo $WAYLAND_DISPLAY`, a text (like `wayland-0`) will be printed only under Wayland.