# Experimental fractional scaling not showing up gnome settings app on 17.10

Tags: scaling

I've seen in a few places that you can enable experimental features to get fractional scaling with the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['scale-monitor-framebuffer']"
```

This doesn't work for me. When I run this command, there are no errors: I can see the correct value showing up in dconf-editor. But the fractional values don't show up in the settings. I can still only see 100%, 200%, and 300%.

I'm using Wayland, all Wayland apps. I'm using the 384.90 Nvidia drivers running on an Nvidia GTX 1080. Running stock, completely unchanged 17.10 (unchanged except for the above command).

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer after changing that setting. How do you know you're using Wayland?

Comment: Yeah just restarted again, no difference in the settings page.

Comment: How do you know you're using Wayland? Because GNOME only offers fractional scaling on Wayland.

Comment: When I was installing the nvidia drivers, I didn't have to quit X. You can't install the nvidia drivers while X is running. Is there a more concrete way of making sure?

Comment: See my answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/968772/1579

Comment: @JeremyBicha Yeah it looks like I'm on X, which is strange. I don't see the option to switch to Wayland using the normal way. Hmm not sure what's going on there, but you answer my question, so thanks.