# No Gear to choose Xorg Session

Tags: xorg, 17.10, wayland

I would like to switch back to Xorg. Unfortunately, I do not see the button to switch the session as mentioned here:
[How do you switch from Wayland back to Xorg in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)

[login screen without desktop environment switcher gear icon (fresh install - ubuntu 17.10.1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmgh8.jpg)

Comment: Just to clarify, it's not a button, but rather a [drop-list on the Gnome login screen](https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/files/2016/03/login.png). You don't see anything there, and you're running 17.10?

Comment: No, there is just the login button, but not the little gear next to it. sorry, dont know how to make a screenshot.

Comment: Try taking a picture of the login screen and adding it to your question. It's peculiar that you don't have the option (via drop-list) for choosing a session type in a default installation of 17.10. BTW, you do need to choose a user before you see the session options.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same "issue".
Turns out that my system is not compatible for wayland, so xorg is used by default - therefore the wayland based desktop didn't even get installed which leads to not even having the option to switch.

I checked my running processes - I run on xorg.

see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904940/how-can-i-tell-if-i-am-running-wayland)

Comment: So there's no solution? I'm trying to use the Gnome shell but don't see a gear icon either, and it appears that my system is also not compatible according to this answer.

Comment: Ah, never mind. I had to install `gnome-shell`, whereas https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/10/install-vanilla-gnome-shell-ubuntu-17-10 just said I had to install `gnome-session`.