# Low Res Boot Screen Resolution Nvidia driver 418 Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, 19.04

I just switched to Ubuntu on my main desktop computer with dual 4k screen. Everything was working fine with the default open source driver for my 1080Ti except shoppy animations.
So I selected the proprietary driver from Nvidia the 418.

Now the boot screen is low resolution and the login screen is on the wrong screen. My primary screen is on the left, secondary is on the right, but the login interface is on the right screen.

Any suggestions?
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hum... Are you sure you are not running wayland? Because it's incompatible with Nvidia drivers. Check this: [How can I tell if I am running Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904940/how-can-i-tell-if-i-am-running-wayland/929678#929678). And maybe this https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-wayland-and-enable-xorg-display-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, I just ran the command and it returned "ubuntu" so according to this post I'm not running Wayland.

Comment: @Gloubountu If it returns "ubuntu" it's running on Wayland; it should return "ubuntu-xorg" if not running on Wayland (and running on Xorg).