# How to close an unexpected window on desktop ubuntu

Tags: 20.04

[image]

I want to close this black frame but I cannot click "Close". Do you know how to close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are running [Xorg and not Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/a/990224/100356)...

1. Open a terminal window
2. Type `xkill` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Click on the black window

Comment: Thank you, it works. But when I restart, the black screen comes back. How to disable it permanently?

Comment: Open a terminal. Execute the command `xdotool selectwindow getwindowname`. After you press Enter, your cursor will change. Click on the black window, and you will see some information output to the terminal. What is this output?

Comment: It shows nothing

Comment: When you open the "Startup Applications" app, what are the applications listed? (You can attach a screenshot or just list them).

Comment: In the Startup Applications app, there are:
- Desktop folder
- Hijra Applet
- im-launch
- SSH Key Agent

Comment: Thank you. I solved it by removing Desktop folder.