# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Container

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk, xserver

I am pretty new to Ubuntu and also new to this forum. Looking for some help.

I've been trying to install Impro-Visor by downloading the Impro-Visor_unix_10_2.sh file and running that in a terminal.

I then get the following error message:

```
Starting Installer ...
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Container
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.init(Unknown Source)
 ..... 
Could not display the GUI. This application needs access to an X Server.
*******************************************************************
You can also run this application in console mode without
access to an X server by passing the argument -c
*******************************************************************
```

I tried:

- Reinstalling Java
- Installing different Java versions
- `xhost +local:` which was a tip I found on the Internet

None of that changed the behavior. If I do use the `-c` option the script runs fine and Impro-Visor does get installed. However, it doesn't launch. The error log says:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so
```

Does anybody know how I can solve this?
Many thanks for good tips.

Comment: Which ubuntu?  Sounds like you are running wayland and not X

Comment: Thanks. I am using version 20.04 lts desktop. Not sure what wayland and x mean? How could I check?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/904940/how-can-i-tell-if-i-am-running-wayland

Comment: Typing echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE gives x11

Comment: That is X, so that was not the issue.  Does the file `/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so` exist?  Does that path exist?

Comment: That file does not exist actually. I do have libawt.so and libawt_headless.so in that location but not libawt_xawt.so. I checked JAVA_HOME (which was empty) and PATH (which didn't contain JAVA_HOME) and then added /usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64/lib to both. Didn't solve the problem. Is the missing file the issue? Did I do something wrong when installing java? Thanks.

Comment: The missing file is probably the issue.  Did you manually install Java 16?  I have java 11 on mine and the libawt_xawt.so file is present.  There is a similar question here that suggests that you have the headless version installed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67391845/exception-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-when-trying-to-open-allure-reports-in-w#comment119119464_67391949

Comment: Ok - that narrowed it down. I reinstalled Java using inline `sudo apt-get update` inline `sudo apt-get upgrade` and then inline `sudo apt-get install openjdk-16-jdk`. Now it works fine. No clue what I did different the first time I installed java but the issue is gone. Thanks a lot for helping me out. Really appreciated.