# How to hide top bar in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-tweak-tool, top-bar

How can I hide top bar in Gnome 3.28 Ubuntu 18.04?

How can the hide-top-bar extension be installed?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

First open the terminal and install `chrome-gnome-shell` package:

```
sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
```

Then install one of these extensions:

- [GNOME Shell integration for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep)
- [GNOME Shell integration for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/)
- [GNOME Shell integration for Opera](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/gnome-shell-integration/)

Finally, head over to the [GNOME Extensions page for the "Hide Top Bar" extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/) and enable the ON/OFF switch for the extension to install.

Comment: The particular "extension to install" is called "Hide Top Bar" (that's obvious from the link, but not from the text of the answer).

Comment: It blows my mind that you have to use a browser plugin to interact with GNOME plugin options. We really need a command line method for this kind of stuff. snaps broke it apparently: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034688/url-extensions-gnome-org-for-managing-gnome-extensions-not-working-in-any-browse ...

Answer (score 30):

For reference, install gnome-tweaks and run:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-autohidetopbar
```

Then log out and back in.  The option to auto hide the top bar will be available from gnome-tweaks tool in the extensions section.

Comment: This method did not work on Ubuntu 21.10 unfortunately.

Answer (score 11):

The simplest and working way I found is to install the Dash-to-Panel GNOME extension. Works like a charm.

[Dash to Panel Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/)

You can toggle it from the browser itself.

Comment: I like this answer the most, as hiding the topbar looses a lot of functionality, with this solution you still have the statusbar available and the top bar is removed. WIN WIN

Comment: +1 Highly recommended. It comes with loads of other useful customization.

Comment: This one is the best!

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same problem about removing top bar. What I do is hack into the theme css, and edit it in place.

Edit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css, add to the bottom

```
#panel, #panel * { 
    height: 0px; 
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
}
```

The top bar is there, but won't be visible and can't interact with user.

Comment: As @Lee says, it goes at the very end on a new line beneath the final block of css in braces

Answer (score 1):

**`gnome-extensions` command line**

The snapification of browsers broke the `chrome-gnome-shell` method mentioned at https://askubuntu.com/a/1029905/52975 with error message:

> Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected

as mentioned at [Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107848/although-gnome-shell-integration-extension-is-running-native-host-connector-is?noredirect=1&lq=1) so if you don't want to find a non snapified browser, you can download the Zip manually from: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3906/remove-app-menu/ or:

```
wget https://extensions.gnome.org/extension-data/hidetopbarmathieu.bidon.ca.v97.shell-extension.zip
```

You can check your GNOME shell version as shown at: [How do I check my version of GNOME-Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13348/how-do-i-check-my-version-of-gnome-shell) with either:

```
gnome-extensions version
gnome-shell --version
```

to determine which versions are compatible based on the extensions website. Then:

```
gnome-extensions install hidetopbarmathieu.bidon.ca.v97.shell-extension.zip
gnome-extensions enable hidetopbar@mathieu.bidon.ca
```

As soon as you run `enable`, the top bar is immediately gone.

I wish we had a more decent standard single command CLI method, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617288/command-line-tool-to-install-gnome-shell-extensions

Other extensions of interest:

- https://github.com/pixel-saver/pixel-saver worked on Ubuntu 21.10, but I think you have to log out and login again. But running this together with `hidetopbar@mathieu.bidon.ca`, I managed to remove both the top bar and the title bar on Ubuntu 21.10, effectively making all maximized windows become full screen! You can make them not-fullscreen with the default shortcut Alt + F10 if needed (since there's not title bar to click the unmaximize button on).
- https://github.com/franglais125/no-title-bar hides the title bar instead of the top bar

Related:

- [Remove title-bar of all maximized windows in GNOME 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289940/remove-title-bar-of-all-maximized-windows-in-gnome-3)
- [How to open windows directly in full screen mode on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217090/how-to-open-windows-directly-in-full-screen-mode-on-ubuntu-18-04) asks how to remove both title bar and top bar

Tested on Ubuntu 21.10.