# Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, monitoring, system-monitor

On a fresh install of 18.10 I attempted to install CPU usage widget

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/

on that link it errors showing :

> Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected

Comment: fixed it by installing gnome-tweak-tool

Comment: Now you can also use the Gnome Extension Manager standalone app, mentioned here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1403716/420789

Answer (score 61, accepted):

On Ubuntu 22.04 clone the repo https://github.com/paradoxxxzero/gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet and do the manual install as per

```
sudo apt install gir1.2-gtop-2.0 gir1.2-nm-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gnome-system-monitor  gettext  

cd /tmp  #  could be anywhere ... once installed repo code not used
git clone git@github.com:paradoxxxzero/gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet.git

cd gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet
make install
reboot
```

If above fails on Ubuntu 22.04 then just use https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3010/system-monitor-next/

Below is for 20.04 or earlier ...

First install this (its what appears in your error popup):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell
```

However, on a new OS install you will still get errors until you also install these:

```
#  Ubuntu 20.04
sudo apt-get install libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor

# Ubuntu 19.10
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-nm-1.0
```

*Or:*

```
# pre Ubuntu 19.10
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtop-2.0 gir1.2-nm-1.0  gir1.2-clutter-1.0
```

Then bounce your GNOME Shell by typing:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type <kbd>r</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

or bounce from a terminal by running

```
killall -3 gnome-shell
```

Now go back to

- https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/

and turn on the monitor extension. The resource monitor widget will now appear on desktop top status bar.

---

***UPDATE***  On Ubuntu 20.04, after doing the above, if it errors out, run the following in a terminal:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paradoxxxzero/gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet/fac6b7646346264bd75813a9d606dd5ba5152d6b/system-monitor%40paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com/extension.js -O ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com/extension.js
```

Then bounce your GNOME Shell using:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type <kbd>r</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

I have run fresh installs of Ubuntu 20.04 on a handful of laptops and some work others fail to run this so the mystery continues...

***UPDATE2*** Apparently if you are running Chromium as a Snap in Ubuntu 20.04, this is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1741074). Using Firefox one can circumnavigate this issue and it should work.

**PS** and yes this also works for Ubuntu 21.10 ( as of May 21 2021 )

Comment: Installing `chrome-gnome-shell` package should be enough to fix the "*native host connector is not detected*" issue in general. You may need other packages to fulfil the dependencies of the extension in particular.

Comment: just a quick addendum - as @Ceisc commented here https://askubuntu.com/a/1034692/888540 - "the chrome-gnome-shell doesn't work if you install the version of Chromium that comes from the Ubuntu Software manager package, but does work if you install Chromium via apt"

Comment: When I am trying to install the additional packages with apt, in Ubuntu 19.10 I am getting the following error `E: Package &apos;gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0&apos; has no installation candidate`

Comment: @lefterav gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 has been replaced by gir1.2-nm-1.0

Comment: None of these helped me with Chromium (both snap and apt versions). But it did work with Brave browser (which is based on Chromium) with the same Chrome extesion.

Comment: @MantasLukosevicius  what Ubuntu are you on ?  above works on 20.04 with firefox

Comment: @ScottStensland Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @ScottStensland what was different for me is that I couldn't run your last wget command, because I didn't have the 'extensions' folder in my '~/.local/share/gnome-shell/' so I created such dir and then that second one. And then i run that command. If this helps at all.

Comment: `Unable to locate package gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor` on Ubuntu 20

Comment: I have the same problem as Mantas. Ubuntu 20.04 and Chromium. With Firefox works well

Comment: I have Ubuntu 20.04LTS. Above suggestion not effective. Same error and no install button visible.

Comment: I'm on Firefox. I think this "extension" is a time waster. What will it do anyways ?

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: For Ubuntu 22.04 with snap firefox: `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager`

Comment: I got a message about msgfmt not found when running make install.   Easily fixed by apt-get installing gettext.   Please add it to the `apt-get install` in your Ubuntu 22.04 instructions.  Thanks.

Comment: @BryanLarsen  Done