# Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected in 19.10

Tags: snap, 19.10, browser, gnome-shell-extension

I just installed Ubuntu 19.10 with GNOME Shell 3.34.1 and I would like to use gnome-shell-extensions using extension in Chromium browser, so I installed [Gnome Shell Integration](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep?hl=cs).

However, when I go to https://extensions.gnome.org, an error appears:

> Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected.

I found a [topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107848/although-gnome-shell-integration-extension-is-running-native-host-connector-is) with same problem, so I also install:

```
sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager
```

However, even after computer restart, error message is still there. I have same problem in Mozilla Firefox.

I installed Chromium as

```
sudo snap install chromium
```

and Firefox from Ubuntu Software Center.

Is there any way to find out what is wrong?

Comment: @pomsky Should be, I installed Chromium as `sudo snap install chromium` and Firefox from Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: @pomsky Thank you, from Ubuntu Software add-ons I am able to install extensions.