# GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected in 21.10

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I have followed the Q&A in this link:
[Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107848/although-gnome-shell-integration-extension-is-running-native-host-connector-is)

But still no working in any browser Chrome, Brave nor Firefox. I have deleted and re-installed the connector restarted gnome but the browser still shows the message in the title. I would rather not install Chrome from snap. Anyone got some new ideas, would be appreciated.

Comment: 21.10 uses Gnome 40 are you sure this feature works in this version of Gnome?

Comment: @David yes that continues to work

Comment: Thanks @vanadium now I know.

Answer (score 4):

You are running 21.10. This lets me to believe that your Firefox is now installed as a snap package. In 21.10, Firefox by default comes as a snap. Verify by looking in the Snap store or by finding "firefox" in the output of `snap list`.

Unfortunately, a browser installed as a snap cannot connect to the main system, thus also not to the connector "chrome-gnome-shell", which establishes the communication between the Gnome Shell Extensions website and Gnome Shell.

There are two ways around

1. You install Gnome Shell extensions manually instead of directly from the website. That is not very difficult. Note also that quite some extensions come with the default Ubuntu software center. Installing software from there is officially supported, and the extension is packed and tested to work with the Ubuntu desktop.
2. You could remove the snap version of the browser, and install the regular version instead. The regular `.deb` version is still available in Ubuntu 21.10. It can be expected that that will not anymore be the case for the forthcoming LTS 22.04.

A potential 3rd workaround: If you have Flatpak enabled, you can install [Extension Manager](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.mattjakeman.ExtensionManager), a GTK4 desktop application that allows to browse and install extensions without having to use a browser.

Comment: please elaborate "install Gnome Shell extensions manually". Thanks!