# KDE Connect on Ubuntu 20.04 not getting detected or showing devices

Tags: 20.04, kde

I have been trying to connect my phone to my Ubuntu PC (20.04). I installed the apps on both of my devices (installed KDE Connect from Snap on Ubuntu, and on the phone, I installed it from the Play Store). The problem is that the devices do not see each other (they are connected to the same internet). But when I installed the KDE Connect app on my Windows 11 PC, the phone gets detected and the Windows PC gets detected by the phone.

These are the things that I have tried:

- Reinstall the KDE Connect app on both devices.
- Disable the firewall on Ubuntu.
- Looking at questions related to this (nothing worked)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you are using Ubuntu with GNOME shell, so could try to install the extension `GSConnect`: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect 
Both are the same, but GSConnect it seems is more stable in the GNOME shell.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon It won't let me download it. It keeps giving me the error: `Although the GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected. Refer to the documentation for instructions about installing connector.`

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I also installed the `chrome-gnome-shell` (native host connector). It is still not working.

Comment: I never had those problems when I used GNOME, but according to this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107848/although-gnome-shell-integration-extension-is-running-native-host-connector-is 
You may have to install some dependencies besides the `chrome-gnome-shell` that you installed.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I found an easy solution. I will post an answer tomorrow.

Comment: Great! It will be very useful for other people

Answer (score 4):

I added ip-address manually - not found.
Then I opened the firewall with:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 1714:1764 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1714:1764 -j ACCEPT
```

that helped.
Good luck!

Comment: Would be similar to `sudo ufw allow proto tcp from 192.168.0.0/16 to any port 1714:1764 comment 'kdeconnect'` (and for `udp`)