# GNOME shell extension doesn't work with snap version of web-browser

Tags: command-line, firefox, gnome-shell, snap, gnome-shell-extension

Got an error from Firefox saying :

> Although the GNOME Shell integration extension is active, the native host connector is not recognized. Please consult the installation manual.

Which is an error that seems to never happen, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 (Dual Boot Windows 10), and yes GNOME shell is installed via

```
sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell
```

I'm using Firefox v64.0.2 (64 bits) snap.

Could someone help?

Comment: 64.0.2 (64 bits) - ( I removed the one that come with it (but it didn't worked either at the time) for the newest ) . And yes i'm in a GNOME session : it echoed `ubuntu:GNOME`

Comment: Snap package comming with the Ubuntu software library yep

Comment: In Ubuntu 21.10, by default, the snap version of Firefox is installed, although you can easily uninstall it and switch to the APT version of Firefox.

Comment: This is the bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1741074

Comment: The Snap version of Firefox does now include the native messaging support needed for the GNOME Shell Extensions add-on. It's no longer necessary to remove the Snap version or to use other browsers or workarounds. See [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1490021/237387).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to install extensions from extensions.gnome.org as they are also available in 'Ubuntu Software' app.

Launch Ubuntu Software, click add-ons, click extensions tab. Here you are able to install extensions.

Comment: Perfect, a bit messy interface to search in (no ranking) but as said by pomsky, hope they'll correct their bug. Thank you !

Comment: This appears to be the only viable solution in Ubuntu 18.04 currently.  Thank You!

Comment: There is no "add-ons" in Ubuntu Software for Ubuntu 21.10 anymore

Comment: Indeed @StR, I also see no "add-dons" or "extensions" tab (Ubuntun 22.04). However, there is a lens icon to search for the extension by its name. After installation, I had to restart the sessions to see the extension in the Gnome extension manager though

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using the snap version of Firefox 64.0.2, it's not unexpected given various restrictions of snappy.

This issue is already raised in snapcraft forum: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/firefox-snap-is-unable-to-access-chrome-gnome-shell-connector/4562, but unfortunately no solutions were provided there.

Similar issue can be seen with the Chromium snap too: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/chrome-gnome-shell-does-not-work-with-chromium-snap/3377/2
(see the [bug-report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1741074))

Answer (score 4):

Gnome extensions cannot be installed with the sandboxed snap versions of Firefox and Chromium.

However it is easy enough to install through the command line. Just download the extension from the https://extensions.gnome.org/ site then from a terminal run `gnome-extensions install /path/to/extension.zip`

You may need to logout and in again for the extension to appear in the list.

Comment: I had to enable the extension after installing. This is possible either through `gnome-extensions enable name-of-extension` or through the GUI of `gnome-shell-extenstion-manager`.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 20.04, I have also noticed that both snap installed Chromium and Brave Web browsers fails to work with the `gnome-shell-integration` extension. Brave is a derivative of Chromium.

In the case of Brave, this issue is overcome by following Brave's instruction on installing the `.deb` versions of the brave-browser and brave-keyring files.

```
$ sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl
$ sudo curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg
$ echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main"|sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install brave-browser
```

However, the chromium-browser does not have an equivalent `.deb` package to overcome this issue. If one does issue the command `sudo apt install chromium-browser`,
this command will instead instruct snap to install chromium.

The `gnome-shell-integration` extension does work with Firefox. It is a preinstalled `.deb pkg` of Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

One option to bypass the problem is to use the application "[Extensions Manager](https://github.com/mjakeman/extension-manager)" (not to be confused with "Extensions") instead of Firefox with the GNOME extension add-on. You can do the whole process of searching and installing extensions within the app. [It can be installed](https://github.com/mjakeman/extension-manager#-installing) via flathub, or e.g. with `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager`.