# Combine the shell and the top bar

Tags: gnome-shell, style

I'd like to combine the shell bar and the top bar on my desktop for all applications.

I have noted on the screenshot below what I mean by shell bar and top bar.

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Unite GNOME Shell Extension.

First make sure that you have `chrome-gnome-shell` installed:

```
sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
```

You also need the *GNOME Shell integration* browser extension installed. You can install the extension in Firefox by visiting [this page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/) and clicking the *Add to Firefox* button or in Chrome, by visiting [this page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep?hl=en) and clicking the *Add to Chrome* button.

Allso install Tweaks to access the extension's options (and a bunch of other useful GNOME settings):

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Now, you can visit the [Unite GNOME Shell Extension webpage](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/), toggle the switch on the right-hand side of the page to *ON* and click *Install* on the pop-up.

Then, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, input `r` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to restart GNOME Shell to make the extension take effect.

To disable The extension, go to *Tweaks* → *Extensions* and toggle the *Unite* extension *OFF*. To uninstall it, visit its website and click the "X" button on the right-side.

Comment: I don't know why but, it wasn't working on Chromium (maybe because it's not Chrome), but it worked on Firefox. Thank you very much for your help and for the correction, I also corrected the error on the screenshot.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Comment: @gogor44 It should work with Chromium too, [unless you're using the snap version instead of the traditional apt version](https://askubuntu.com/q/1111784/480481).