# GNOME Shell extensions not working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: firefox, gnome-shell-extension, 22.04

I followed the instructions on https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-gnome-shell-extensions-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish-linux-desktop
to install GNOME Shell extensions, but I still get the error:

> Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected. Refer to documentation for instructions about installing connector.

Comment: This is because you're running the snap version of Firefox. SNAP REMOVE it and install the apt/deb version. Instructions can be found elsewhere here on AU. Or use the Extensions Manager app, or use Chrome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Gnome Shell Extensions 22.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404497/install-gnome-shell-extensions-22-04-lts)

Comment: This article may help you:
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/install-firefox-deb-ubuntu-22-04/ from what i understand, the apt/deb file just refers back to the snap version, so the ppa instructions at that link should get you the non-snap version. Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected" error in 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403688/although-gnome-shell-integration-extension-is-running-native-host-connector-is)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The current version of the browser Firefox is packaged as a snap version. One of the issues with this is that it cannot work with the Gnome Extensions website.

The current work around is to install a desktop application that allows to search for and install extensions.

[image]

Look for "Extension manager" in the software store, or install with a terminal command:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
```

Comment: This app doesn't load anything in its search page. Do you have the same?

Comment: @RezaTaba I guess you are facing this bug: https://github.com/mjakeman/extension-manager/issues/470

Answer (score 2):

Install `gnome-browser-connector` manually from its [GitLab repo](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-browser-connector) by following these instructions:

1. Install `chrome-gnome-shell` and `meson`:

   ```
   sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell meson
   ```
2. `cd` to wherever you like to clone the git repo (e.g. `Downloads`):

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   ```
3. Clone the git repo:

   ```
   git clone https://gitlab.gnome.org/nE0sIghT/gnome-browser-connector.git
   ```
4. `cd` to the cloned directory:

   ```
   cd gnome-browser-connector
   ```
5. Then follow the build instructions in the [README](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-browser-connector/-/blob/master/README.md):

   > ```
   > meson --prefix=/usr builddir
   > cd builddir
   > meson install
   > ```

I found the instructions on [Reddit by Rob217](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/wgxvvp/comment/ilolp6d/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)
and they worked for me on Ubuntu 22.10.

Answer (score 0):

## Native Connector is supported now

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 and I can confirm that the Snap version of Firefox **does work** with the Gnome Extensions website.

All I had to do was install the connector like usual:

```
sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
```

And then install the Firefox add-on when prompted by the [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org) website.

After reloading the page there was an OS pop-up message to grant permission to the native connector.

---

## References

I couldn't find a whole lot of information on this, there's far more search results that say "uninstall the Snap version" than there are that say that it now works just fine with Gnome Extensions. I did find [this blog post](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/11/firefox-ubuntu-22-04-native-messaging/) though, which linked through to [this call for testing on the Ubuntu Community Discourse](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/call-for-testing-native-messaging-support-in-the-firefox-snap/29759) site.

Screenshot from [UbuntuHandbook](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/11/firefox-ubuntu-22-04-native-messaging/):

[image: screenshot showing native connector permission dialog box]