# Anydesk freezes (clicking not working) a portion of right side upper corner in ubuntu 23.04

Tags: anydesk

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 23.04 (beta). I have set anydesk for background running. After successfully upgrading to the 23.04, I found a rectangular area nearer to the right upper corner repeatedly opening anydesk on the right click on it. While using other applications, there is no response to click on it. That means I can't do minimize, maximize or close the respective window while moving the window out of that certain area every click works as usual. So I uninstall anydesk which solves my problem.

I really need to use anydesk. Can anyone help me to solve the issue ?

Comment: you need to report it as a bug. 23.04 has not been officially released yet

Comment: This is still the case after 23.04 release

Answer (score 4):

I used this command **sudo systemctl restart gdm3** to restart the desktop which clears the problem, the problem returns when anydesk is used next time, so only a clumsy workaround.
Also you can swap the corners of the title bar buttons using Tweaks.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Mine solved by disabling Enable legacy tray icon support of App Indicator

Comment: This is worked for me after install the gnome-extension-manager as it was not installed. I followed this post
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406598/gnome-shell-extensions-not-working-in-ubuntu-22-04

Answer (score 2):

It's because of anydesk.

Just simply go to `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com`

```
 cd /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
```

and check  `appIndicator.js` file is present or not by.

```
ls
```

if file is there just simply rename it with `appIndicator.bak`.

```
sudo mv appIndicator.js appIndicator.bak
```

and just restart your system.

```
reboot
```

now you can use anydesk without any issue. what it does is it will lose the app indicators in the top right corner but now that area is clickable.

Comment: thanks, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Disabling anydesk service resolved the issue since it will halt autostart after each reboot.

To disable anydesk:

```
systemctl disable anydesk.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following workaround:

- Installed a virtualbox on ubuntu 23.04;
- Installed windows 11 inside virtualbox;
- Inside windows 11, installed the Anydesk;
- Use Anydesk inside windows 11, inside dropbox, inside Ubuntu.

I hope it helps.

Best regards