# Gnome Extensions - OpenWeather

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I am having issues with Ubuntu 20.04 re Gnome Extensions, especially **OpenWeather**, which I seem to have lost since upgrading from 18.04. I have not had a problem previously installing it, but now it seems complicated to do so.

I came across [this website](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/750/openweather/) which hints that it now needs to be installed as a browser extension. Really? They then go on to mention that I need an *extensions default key*. I have no idea what that is or what to do with it if I was fortunate enough to know what it is. I then managed to find a [Gitlab page](https://gitlab.com/jenslody/gnome-shell-extension-openweather) where they had more sensible suggestions to install it, and managed to do so from terminal with `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extension-weather`. However even though I now can see OpenWeather as an extension in **Tweaks**, unfortunately it shows up with an orange triangle with an exclamation mark beside it, and will not switch on.

In short, does anyone know how to get Openweather to work from here, because as far as Ubuntu 20.04 is concerned I no longer have a clue?

Comment: Just another reason **not** to upgrade to 20.04 yet.

Comment: as I know all that nice things like extension are saved and configured in the home directory, then I'd try to create a new user then try to install the extension that that user. If it works then I'd move all my data on the new user directory. (obviously you don't have to move the gnome-shell configurations files.) [here is the doc to create a new user](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-add.html.en)

Comment: You can turn it off and on from https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/750/openweather/ and you can completely remove extensions from https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ that will then allow you to reinstall it from the first link.

Comment: "hints that it now needs to be installed as a browser extension" ... are you seeing a message asking  for the GNOME Shell host connector to be installed? https://askubuntu.com/a/1034692/158442?

Comment: @Terrance Sorry, but I'm still totally clueless as to how to get OpenWeather to work or what you're talking about. I've already explained it's turned off because I am unable to turn it on as it shows an exclamation error. I've now deleted OpenWeather. Can you please tell me how one installs it so that it WORKS.

Comment: @GyroGearloose There's no reason not to upgrade to 20.04.1.

Comment: @heynnema when I look at the new questions, I see lots of reasons. Latest is https://askubuntu.com/q/1286542/778232

Comment: @GyroGearloose In the link that you provided, how does their hard disk is too full, relate to your comment about 20.04? Absolutely nothing.

Comment: @PaulBenson Status please...

Comment: @heynnema just another problem with 20.x: https://askubuntu.com/q/1286542/778232 the shear amount of "complaints/urgent questions/problem reports/misunderstandings on how to do it" is enough for me to stick to "never change a running system". Sorry to annoy you, but that's what I see and hear. 20.4 is not mature yet.

Comment: @heynnema Not sure what you mean. If you mean have I got OW working, the answer is 'yes', but it was a reboot that finally got it going - API key **not** needed. I've moved back to 18.04 now as I agree with GyroGearloose. 20.04 is crap, and not just for my troubles with OW.

Comment: @PaulBenson A gnome-shell restart would have probably also fixed OW. Some gnome-shell extensions require an update to work with 20.04. Best to temporarily disable them all to see if 20.04 then runs OK. I'd say... give it another try, but don't give up so easily :-)

Comment: @heynnema, I agree with GyroGearloose, with every upgrade there are some advantages and disadvantages. So it's best to stick to a LTS version as long as possible.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to enable Firefox to manage your local Gnome-Shell extensions.

Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/, and check if you need to install two pieces of software. Just follow the onscreen instructions.

Then go to https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/750/openweather/ to enable the OpenWeather extension. Once installed, go to https://openweathermap.org to obtain a free **personal API key**, and paste it in in the OpenWeather settings panel. See image below...

[image]

**Update #1:**

In newer versions of OpenWeather, instead of obtaining a free **personal API key**, you can just flip the **Use extensions api-key for openweather.org** to ON.

Comment: Good answer!  I forgot that OpenWeather went over to API Key now.  =)

Comment: @Terrance Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything but ultimately I uninstalled Chromium (obtained Ubuntu Software) and installed Chrome by downloading directly from Google. I was then able to get the Gnome extension working in Chrome and was able to install the OpenWeather extension. I read that some Snap installations are problematic.