# Main HD is full. Home Assistant on Docker installation

Tags: 20.04, disk-usage

A few days ago I noticed "/" reached 95% without doing anything (by myself). I noticed this in my [Home Assistant](https://www.home-assistant.io/) UI (see screen capture below)

[Home Assistant Supervisor Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHy5w.png)

Home Assistant is running on Docker.

```
root@zeus:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           364M  2.6M  361M   1% /run
/dev/sda2       458G  436G     0 100% /
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop2       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1885
/dev/loop1       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10126
/dev/loop3       71M   71M     0 100% /snap/lxd/16922
/dev/loop0       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10185
tmpfs           364M     0  364M   0% /run/user/1000
```

As you can see, `/dev/sda2` (notebook internal HD) is full.

Before upgrading to 20.04.1 LTS I did not notice the `/dev/loop[n]` filesystems.

How can I determine the cause of this increment?

TIA

Comment: Check `ls -lh /var/log` for an exceptionally large logfile. Also check your HomeAssistant directory for a sudden logfile or database growth.

Comment: That command shows one large file:
`-rw-r-----  1 syslog    adm             7.6G Oct 24 14:34 kern.log`

Comment: Delete it. It will start anew. Start looking at the new file immediately -- something is very wrong, and your system is begging you to investigate and fix it.

Comment: Deleted kern.log, it generated a new one. Now looking at it (tail -f /var/log.kern.log). Nothing shows up, file size is 0. All I get is the message in the screen (laptop):

`EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): __ext4_find_entry:1531: inode #34340865: comm backup cleanup: reading directory lblock 0`

Comment: Troubleshooting whatever the problem is seems a different, though understandably related, question. You asked about determining why a storage device is full, and you now have the proximate cause (enormous log file; one of the most common reasons). Please start a new question to troubleshoot/understand your kernel/filesystem error.

Answer (score 1):

Your storage device is full due to a "runaway" log file taking up 7.6GB.

This is one of the most common causes of a full storage device.

The log file itself is not broken. Your system is encountering some problem very frequently (sometimes one or more times each second), and logging about it every time.

The temporary workaround is to delete the log file. It will promptly regenerate (empty) on it's own, and will promptly start growing again.

The real solution is to investigate the log file, identify whatever problem(s) are causing the tremendous log activity, and fix it(them).

Comment: Thanks. I created a new question