# Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 EXT4-fs error (device sdb1)

Tags: 20.04, filesystem, ext4, inode

This comes from [Main HD is full. Home Assistant on Docker installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286542/main-hd-is-full-home-assistant-on-docker-installation)

After deleting /var/log/kern.log (which was about 8GB) I started monitoring it (tail) and nothing was written to it.

All I can see now is the following output to stdout (its a laptop):

`EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): __ext4_find_entry:1531: inode #34340865: comm backup cleanup: reading directory lblock 0`