# Gnome browser addon for installing extensions does not work on Firefox in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: gnome, firefox, snap, gnome-shell-extension, 21.10

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10 and found that the browser addon for installing Gnome extensions doesn't seem to be working with Firefox. I get the following error when I visit https://extensions.gnome.org/:

`Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected. Refer documentation for instructions about installing connector.`

I have installed `chrome-gnome-shell` but it doesn't work. It was working just fine on previous versions. I suspect that it may have something to do with Firefox being packaged as a Snap by default in 21.10.

Does anybody know a fix for this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL extensions.gnome.org for managing GNOME Extensions not working in any browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034688/url-extensions-gnome-org-for-managing-gnome-extensions-not-working-in-any-browse)

Comment: @Liso This is a 21.10-specific problem. Your link is too old.

Comment: @Nmath This is a 21.10-specific problem. Your link is too old.

Comment: I've filed this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chrome-gnome-shell/+bug/1947579

Comment: @Flim your bug report was closed as a duplicate of [Bug #1741074](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1741074) (it would have been surprising if that hadn't been reported already…). Looking at the last comments, it seems very unlikely to get fixed for 21.10 though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because when you installed/upgraded to 21.10, the `Software Updater` uninstalled your previous .deb version of Firefox, and installed a SNAP version of Firefox.

There are two possible ways to fix this...

1. Start the `Ubuntu Software` application and search for "Firefox". You'll find two of them. One will show as installed... that would be the SNAP version. Uninstall it and install the other (.deb version of) Firefox.
2. Or, using the command line in `terminal`:

   `sudo snap remove firefox`

   `sudo apt update`

   `sudo apt install firefox`

Comment: Will I keep all my Firefox settings and history if I switch from the snap version of Firefox to the APT one, and vice-versa?

Comment: I just tried it. Firefox settings and history is not shared or copied when switching from snap to the APT version of Firefox. But it did fix this issue with GNOME Extensions.

Comment: @Flimm If you sign into your Firefox account, it'll sync whatever bookmarks and history you had before.