# How to hide the workspaces from the app picker?

Tags: gui, workspaces, menu, gnome-shell-extension

So, basically, I don't want the workspaces to show in the applications menu (app picker?) window. They're already there when I click activities, so I don't need the redundancy. Solutions?

I imagine I could do this with a Gnome Extension, but I've never written one (all my knowledge of programming is resumed to a Java For Dummies book and a few years working with PHP/CSS). If anyone could give me some pointers on how to start, I'd be very glad.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Workspaces in the application menu allows you to directly drag application icons to open them in specific workspaces. So they actually make sense there. But yes, there are extensions allowing to hide them.

Comment: @vanadium To be honest, I just think they look ugly there lol. I rarely use workspaces anyway, so getting rid of them is the sensible option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the Worskspaces boxes in the Application Grid using the [Just Perfection GNOME Shell extension](https://gitlab.gnome.org/jrahmatzadeh/just-perfection).

It is an extension that is able to disable GNOME Shell UI elements, change the behavior and customize the GNOME Shell Desktop.
You can install the extension right from the [GNOME extension website](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3843/just-perfection/) with a simple toggle.

Preconditions for the installation from the GNOME extension website is the installation of the package `chrome-gnome-shell` (running in a terminal `sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell`) and the usage of a non-snap application browser (currently, `firefox` installed as a snap package does not support the installation of extension from the extension website).
For further details about how to install an extension, refer to the answers of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1403688/1037999).

After Just Perfection extension installation, open its preferences, clicking the [cog](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3843/just-perfection/) or using the `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` app (you can install it running in a terminal `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-prefs`), see screenshot below:

[image: Extensions menu]

Find the setting called "Workspace App Grid" and disable it, like in the screenshot below (my system uses a Italian locale):

[image: Just Perfection screenshot]

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much.