# How to connect Android to Ubuntu 22.04 Jellyfish?

Tags: gnome, android, gnome-shell-extension, 22.04

I used GSConnect and F-droid until I upgraded to Jellyfish. Now the extension is not compatible with Jellyfish since it's not working on Firefox. I have tried Extension Manager, but it still doesn't allow me to install GSConnect.

Is there any alternative to connect Android devices to Ubuntu for this new LTS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

GSConnect does actually support GNOME 42 and Ubuntu 22.04, as you can see in the [extension's webpage](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/):

> [image: GSConnect supported versions]

The issue of not being able to install the extension using Firefox exists because, since Ubuntu 21.10, [Firefox is a snap application](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/09/ubuntu-makes-firefox-snap-default). The Firefox snap, however, is not configured correctly, so it doesn't let you install GNOME extensions.

- Related: ["Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected" error in 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1403688/618353)

There are several ways to overcome this problem:

1. The recommended way to install GSConnect in Ubuntu 22.04 is to use GNOME Extension Manager, which you can install by running in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
   ```

   Then you can open the Extension Manager, click on the *Browse* tab, search for "gsconnect" and install the extension.

   [image: Extension Manager]

   If you had the extension already installed, try to remove it, log out and log back in, and search for it again.
2. GSConnect also exists in the default Ubuntu repositories, so you can install it by running the following `apt` command in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect
   ```

   After installing it, you'll probably need the Extension Manager to enable and configure the extension.
3. Alternatively, you have the option to remove the Firefox snap package and replace it with the `.deb` one by following the instructions in [Archisman Panigrahi's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/618353) in [How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 or later versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22).
4. Finally, you also have the option of using a web browser other than Firefox and install GNOME Shell extensions with [the usual procedure](https://askubuntu.com/a/757326/618353).

Comment: Just installed it via the new extension manager and works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I found KDE connect to work well: need to be installed both on ubuntu (not within firefox) and on android.

Kde connect ubuntu: https://kdeconnect.kde.org/download.html
Kde connect android: same link