# Why does It say I need to install a native host connector when I already have it installed? (Gnome Extensions)

Tags: gnome-shell-extension

I already `ran chrome-gnome-shell`, but it still says I need to install a native host connector:

[image: check the photo here]

Any fixes?

Comment: Silly question, but have you restarted your browser since installing the connector? 

Comment: yes I have, I also restarted my pc, but same thing still

Comment: which OS and version are you running? If 22.04 LTS GNOME 42.1 does not run the GNOME Shell Extensions with wayland windowing system. I you want to use the legacy extensions, you will need to remove FF snap and replace it with the APT version. Other than that you should now use GNOME Extension Manager.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected" error in 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403688/although-gnome-shell-integration-extension-is-running-native-host-connector-is)

Answer (score -1):

Restart your shell with something like:

`source ~/.bashrc`

Otherwise try reinstalling it via:

```
sudo apt-get purge chrome-gnome-shell
sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell
```

...and see if that helps.