# How do I move hot corner thap opens Activities Overview from top left to top right corner?

Tags: 22.04

In Ubuntu 22.04 -> Settings -> Multitasking you can enable the hot corner that opens Activities Overview but it doesn't provide an option to select which corner will trigger it.

How can I change the corner that triggers it from top left to top right?

Comment: AFAIK there's only that corner for that purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tested in my machine, with Ubuntu 22.04 and Gnome Shell 42.1.

NOTE: Consider that, with Ubuntu/GNOME version changing every now and then, some extensions may be no longer compatible or create issues. Also extensions are not directly developed by Canonical, that is another reason why sometimes incompatibilities may rise.

You can install a Gnome Shell Extension called [Custom Hot Corners - Extended](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4167/custom-hot-corners-extended) that allows you to configure hot corners for all the four screen corners and customize the action of every hot corner.

In this way, you can set the top-right hot corner for the Activities Overview activation, and disable the top-left hot corner (or set it to a different function).

For example, select the top-right corner icon, Select "Core Actions" and then "Show Activities Overview".

[image: Custom Hot Corners - Extended]
<sup>Picture from [Custom Hot Corners - Extended](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4167/custom-hot-corners-extended)</sup>

A common way to install a Gnome Shell Extension is to install it through `firefox`, however if you have the snap version of `firefox` you can still keep it and use alternative ways to install an extension. Please refer to  ["Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected" error in 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1403688/1037999). These methods are valid even if you don't use `firefox` as your main browser.

Comment: will that shell extension work in 22.04 though with GNOME 4? Won't you need to remove FF as snap and install the APT version in its place first?

Comment: Last extension version supports GNOME 42, according to the Gnome Shell Extension webpage. Now that the `gnome-shell-extension-manager` package is available in Ubuntu repo, there is no need to install from web (so snap version of `firefox` is no longer a showstopper).

Comment: In Gnome Extension Manager it says that this extension is not supported my Gnome Shell version is 42.1

Comment: Now I have access to an Ubuntu machine with Gnome Shell 42.1, I was able to install the extension through Gnome Extension Manager and was able to set the "Show Activities Overview" in the top-right hot corner.

Comment: Had to install it manually from archive but it's working <3 Thank you!

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 fresh install - crashes Extension manager! v0.3. After removing it manager is stable!

Comment: I'm sorry that the solution that worked when I wrote it, now doesn't work for you. I have added a note in my answer. Extensions are not managed directly by canonical, and they may be affected by changes in Ubuntu/Gnome versions.