# Why does Gnome Shell Extensions not work with Firefox in 23.04?

Tags: gnome, firefox, gnome-shell-extension, firefox-extensions

I'm trying to use GNOME extensions in Firefox, but it doesn't seem to work. I keep getting the error `No such native application org.gnome.chrome_gnome_shell`. I've followed the installation guide on LinuxConfig step by step. Not sure if it really makes a difference or not, but I am using the flatpak version of Firefox.

`gnome-shell-extensions` is on the newest version (44.0-1), I've installed the GNOME extension addon into Firefox, installed the latest `chrome-gnome-shell` (version 42.1-3), and I still get the error on the gnome extensions website.

I'm currently working on a fresh install of 23.04. Wiped my harddrive and started from scratch after ditching Windows again. I've done the basic updates and installed my usual programs (discord, steam, etc.) and now looking to do some customization of my Desktop.

I can't understand why this doesn't work. I recall the last time I used Ubuntu I had no issues with installing the GNOME extensions.

Comment: The flatpak variant of Firefox might have a significance... On the other hand, I believe that installing Gnome shell extensions through the browser is just a convenience feature. Perhaps the documentation of the desired extension describes how to install it via the terminal?

Comment: Also, look at this: https://askubuntu.com/q/1403688/1157519