# How to open windows directly in full screen mode on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, fullscreen

Is it possible to have a configuration for opening any window directly in full screen mode? I'm to tired of pressing F11...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some applications such as Evince have options or a command line option that allows to launch them full screen. There is no overall setting that would allow you to automatically open new windows in full screen mode on Gnome Shell, which is the desktop used by Ubuntu 18.04. Still, there are some options.

**1. Modifying the Gnome Shell Desktop**

You can remove the topbar and remove window decorations on maximized windows to have a near-full screen experience.

[Hide top bar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/) will hide your top bar.
[Pixel Saver](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/) will remove legacy title bars from maximized windows

Together, these extensions will give you a near full-screen experience on maximized windows.

**2. Using Devilspie or Devilspie2**

[Devilspie](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie) and [Devilspie2](http://www.nongnu.org/devilspie2/) are old tools still work perfectly on desktops that run on Xorg. You can define rules that need to be applied to newly created windows. As such, you could set that any window is automatically maximized, but you will need to exclude dialog boxes. This can do exactly what you want, but requires tinkling with a config file to set it up initially.